# Using paste0 in left_join R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to use a local variable : col_nom <- paste0("V",i) to setup the name of a column in a loop and then use it in the by argument of a left_join.
But my current code is not working and raise the error " Join columns must be present in data.", it means that my local variable is not recognise as a column of result_knn_df.

result_knn_df has "V1", "V2", ..., "Vk" as columns

Has someone an idea to make this expression recognise as a column name ?

```
for(i in 1:k){
   
   col_nom <- paste0("V",i)
            
   result_knn_df[[paste0("distance",i)]] <- distHaversine(p1 = result_knn_df %>%  
                                                            select(lon,lat),
                                                          p2 =  result_knn_df %>% 
                                                            left_join(fire_station_location %>% 
                                                                        select(LAT, LNG,strong textid_fire_station), 
                                                                      by = c( col_nom = "id_fire_station")) %>% 
                                                            select(LNG,LAT)
                                                          )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could pass a named vector (with `setNames`) in `by` to do the join

```
 for(i in 1:k){

  col_nom <- paste0("V",i)
        
   result_knn_df[[paste0("distance",i)]] <- distHaversine(p1 = result_knn_df %>%  
                                                        select(lon,lat),
                                                      p2 =  result_knn_df %>% 
                                                        left_join(fire_station_location %>% 
                                                                    select(LAT, LNG,strong textid_fire_station), 
                                                                  by = setNames("id_fire_station", col_nom)) %>% 
                                                        select(LNG,LAT)
                                                      )
```